# underlying real vector bundle of a complex vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Let $\eta^\mathbb{C}$ be a complex line bundle. If the underlying $2$-dimensional vector bundle $\eta$ is not trivial as a real vector bundle, can we obtain that  $\eta^\mathbb{C}$ is not trivial as a complex line bundle?

I get confused. Could you give a valid proof? thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, of course; prove the contrapositive.

Comment: Incidentally, the converse is false: A topologically trivial real rank-$2$ bundle over a torus admits a moduli space of non-trivial holomorphic structures, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otherwise a complex trivialization would give you also a real one

$$
E(\eta) \cong B(\eta)\times \mathbb C^n \cong  B(\eta ) \times \mathbb R^{2n}.
$$

Comment: Note that the first isomorphism is actually one of complex bundles. But that means it is a real one just respecting the multiplication.